# fazer uma validação de checkbox por linha de uma tabela

Tags: javascript, jquery

tenho uma pagina com uma tabela onde cada linha tem 3 checkbox e cada coluna tem 11 linhas com os 3 checkbox, precisava fazer uma validação onde pelo menos um checkbox dos 3 de cada linha estiverem marcado, e se em uma linha tiver os 3 checkbox desmarcados trás uma mensagem de erro eu tentei essa logica e não esta dando certo

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
                if($('#ok').not(":checked") && $('#nok').not(":checked") && $('#na').not(":checked")){
                    alert('erro');
                }else if($('#ok1').not(":checked") && $('#nok1').not(":checked") && $('#na1').not(":checked")){
                    alert('erro');
                }else if($('#ok2').not(":checked") && $('#nok2').not(":checked") && $('#na2').not(":checked")){
                    alert('erro');
                }else if($('#ok3').not(":checked") && $('#nok3').not(":checked") && $('#na3').not(":checked")){
                    alert('erro');
                }else if($('#ok4').not(":checked") && $('#nok4').not(":checked") && $('#na4').not(":checked")){
                    alert('erro');
                }else if($('#ok5').not(":checked") && $('#nok5').not(":checked") && $('#na5').not(":checked")){
                    alert('erro');
                }else if($('#ok6').not(":checked") && $('#nok6').not(":checked") && $('#na6').not(":checked")){
                    alert('erro');
                }else if($('#ok7').not(":checked") && $('#nok7').not(":checked") && $('#na7').not(":checked")){
                    alert('erro');
                }else if($('#ok8').not(":checked") && $('#nok8').not(":checked") && $('#na8').not(":checked")){
                    alert('erro');
                }else if($('#ok9').not(":checked") && $('#nok9').not(":checked") && $('#na9').not(":checked")){
                    alert('erro');
                }else if($('#ok10').not(":checked") && $('#nok10').not(":checked") && $('#na10').not(":checked")){
                    alert('erro');
                }else if($('#sim').not(":checked") && $('#nao').not(":checked")){
                    alert('erro');
                }else {
                    alert("checado");
                }
        });
```

alguém pode me dizer onde estou errando, a ideia é que das 11 linhas 1 linha  tem o s 3 checkbox e desses 3 checkbox 1 deve esta marcado de cada linha das 11

tabela 
linha1 [x] [] []
linha2 [] [x] []
linha3 [] [x] []

se tiver assim todas com uma marcação cadastra senão
da erro como no exemplo abaixo

tabela 
linha1 [x] [] []
linha2 [] [] []  <= erro sem marcação
linha3 [] [x] []

Answer (score 2):

Melhor fazer de forma dinâmica, se você tiver de verificar mais linhas vai ter de ficar alterando o código toda hora que adicionar um novo.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#check').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var valido = true;

        $("#tabela tr").each(function(index, el) {
            var $linha = $(el);
            var checked = $linha.find('.opcao:checked').length;
            if (checked == 0 ) {
                valido = false;
                return false;
            }
        });
        console.log('valido ' , valido);
        alert(valido ? 'checado' : 'erro');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tabela">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="opcao"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="opcao"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="opcao"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="opcao"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="opcao"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="opcao"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="opcao"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="opcao"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="opcao"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button id="check"> Validar</button>
```